# Groovy / Spock test a Java class that has a member @Inject

Tags: java, unit-testing, groovy, spock

I am trying to test a Java class that has a member injected using @Inject.

I want to test the someMethod

```
public class SomeJavaClass {

    @Inject
    private SomeFactory someFactory;

    private SomeDAO someMethod(Map someMap) {
        SomeDAO someDAO = someFactory.create();
        //some code
    }
}
```

My class does not have a explicit constructor

Comment: You have to mock the methods in your factory.

Answer (score 1):

If your field is private, and you don't use constructors, how do you inject it? I will assume that this was a mistake, because if you inject something from the outside, you need to provide an interface for it.

So here's a spock spec that does what you ask, but exposes someFactory as a protected member:

```
import spock.lang.Specification
import spock.lang.Subject

import javax.inject.Inject

interface SomeFactory {
    SomeDAO create()
}

class SomeDAO {

}

class SomeJavaClass {

    @Inject
    protected SomeFactory someFactory;

    protected SomeDAO someMethod(Map someMap) {
        SomeDAO someDAO = someFactory.create();
        //some code
    }
}

class SomeJavaClassSpec extends Specification {

    def someFactory = Mock(SomeFactory)
    @Subject
    SomeJavaClass subject = new SomeJavaClass(
            someFactory: someFactory
    )

    def "It uses a factory to create some object"() {
        when:
        subject.someMethod([:])

        then:
        1 * someFactory.create() >> new SomeDAO()
    }
}
```

You can also use the spock collaborators extension annotations to inject your collaborator Mocks automatically:

https://github.com/marcingrzejszczak/spock-subjects-collaborators-extension

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can inject to private fields (Guice and Spring can do that). You can use my extension but it would be much better if you added the constructor since then it follows the OOP practices.

Comment: Also, it is possible with reflection and if it this was Groovy class it would be even easier with .@ operator. Just for future readers of this answer.

Comment: You're right, that's true with the ".@" operator :) But maybe let's not propagate such terrible hacks :D

Comment: If it is in official API then it is not a hack :D